# Access denied error while using environment variables

Tags: sql, node.js, environment-variables

I am using SQL for the first time.
I am using a docker container to run my SQL
In my node.js application i ran the followig

```
let con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "user",
    password: "password"
})
  
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
})
```

it got connected. But when i am using the environment variablesi am getting an error

```
let con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: process.env.USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD
})
  
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
})
```

I am getting the following errors.

```
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
errno: 1045,
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'vidhyanand'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)",
sqlState: '28000',
fatal: true
```

Comment: Are you sure that the username and the password are correct?

Comment: yes. I tried console.log

Comment: I would test getting into MySQL via CLI. Try running the following command: `mysql -h 172.17.0.1 -u vidhyanand -p`. It should prompt you to type in your password. Type in your password and let's see whether your direct access was successful.